# Selecting name of the excel sheet while loading an excel file with tablib

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-import-export

I have an excel file to load with 4 sheets.
I want to load a specific sheet from.
How can I choose the name of the sheet?

This doesn't help. I can't choose a specific sheet.

```
imported_data= dataset.load(file.read( ), format= 'xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
for dataset in imported_data.sheets():
    print(dataset.title)  # returns the names of the sheets
    print(dataset)  # returns the data in each sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `tablib.Databook()`

```
imported_data = tablib.Databook()  
imported_data.xlsx = file.read()
for dataset in imported_data.sheets():
    if dataset.title == 'name of the sheet':
       #do anything
```