# Django Import Export, how to import specific sheet in excel?

Tags: django, django-import-export

What is the correct way to import specific sheet of excel by using Django-Import-Export Module??

or if possible. all the sheets in a workbook one by one...

I referred their documentation and it was not much helpful

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

the same way I would like to export data into one workbook from multiple sheets...

how do achieve it??

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030949/selecting-name-of-the-excel-sheet-while-loading-an-excel-file-with-tablib) help?

Comment: did you try `xlrd`? its a good choice for working with excel files

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete answer for my question

```py
databook = Databook()    
imported_data= databook.load(file.read( ), format= 'xlsx')
        
for dataset in imported_data.sheets():
    print(dataset.title)  # returns the names of the sheets
    print(dataset)  # returns the data in each sheet
```

This is how you can export your multiple datasets in one excel file

```py
book = tablib.Databook((data1, data2, data3))
    
with open('students.xls', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(book.export('xls'))
```

[documentation](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using use pyexcel_xls package on django it's fairly easy to use.

```
from pyexcel_xls import get_data as xls_get
def import_excel(request):
    excel_file = request.FILES['file']
    #uploading the excel file
    if (str(excel_file).split('.')[-1] == "xls"):
        data = xls_get(excel_file, column_limit=15)
    elif (str(excel_file).split('.')[-1] == "xlsx"):
        data = xlsx_get(excel_file, column_limit=15)

    if (len(data['sheet1']) > 2): #reading of records begins from second row
        name = data['sheet1']  #excel sheet name you wish to get
        for l in range(2, len(name)): #loop through the number of rows in the sheet
            data = name[l][0] #extract the first column's data
```